# Have a Javascript which works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple javascript to select all check boxes. It works in two browsers but not one. Can anyone help me with this script to make it compatible with IE8 or above.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function toggle(source) {

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('marked[]');

  for(var i in checkboxes)

    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;

}

</script>

    <p>

        <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All

    </p>
```

Thanks,

Jonah

Comment: I think you have a syntax error on `getElementsByName` selection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try plain loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

The `getElementsByName` returns HTMLCollection which is not plain array, and probably treated differently in each browser. Most likely Firefox and Chrome returns the indices when using the `for(var i in checkboxes)` loop while IE returns the items themselves - plain loop should solve this, as the basic syntax is the same for all browsers.

Comment: @Jack thanks, looks like IE is returning the item itself meaning `i` in the `for(var i in checkboxes)` loop is the actual checkbox..

Comment: @ShadowWizard: [nitpick] `getElementsBy*` doesn't return an array, but an `HTMLCollection` object, which has characteristics very similar to an array object, but doesn't behave quite the same

Comment: Nice one Shadow Wizard.  Works a charm now.